# creating an encoded column of a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A column in my pandas dataframe has one of the following values [excellent, good, average, bad, very bad]. I want to create a column in the same dataframe with each of ***[excellent, good, average, bad, very bad]*** being converted to ***[EX, G, Avg, B, VB]*** respectively.

I searched for it but most of the answers are explained using scikit-learn which I am not quite familiar with. Is there a way it can be done using pandas?

Comment: without using pandas?

Comment: Do you think without or with pandas?

Comment: A typo. Corrected it already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `dict` created with `zip`:

```
L1 = ['excellent', 'good', 'average', 'bad', 'very bad']
L2 = ['EX', 'G', 'Avg', 'B', 'VB']

df['col'] = df['col'].map(dict(zip(L1, L2)))
```

**Detail**:

```
print (dict(zip(L1, L2)))
{'excellent': 'EX', 'good': 'G', 'average': 'Avg', 'bad': 'B', 'very bad': 'VB'}
```

Comment: @MihirShanvir - First is created `dictionary`, added `detail`. Then `map` - replace values of column from keys to values of dictionary.